# UPDATE WHERE PossibleParentItem IN ParentItems

Tags: sql-server, in-clause, sql-update

I'm stuck on this query: I would like to UPDATE each row in temp table #tmpHierarchy and set pLevel = 3, if the row has no level set yet (= 99) and one of it's [possible] parent items is contained in the temp table and has level = 2.

Table items contains all items, table ParentItems contains links between Items (fields Item, ParentItem)

Something like:

```
UPDATE #tmpHierarchy SET pLevel = 3 WHERE pLevel = 99 
      AND (
               (
               SELECT Item FROM Items as IT LEFT JOIN ParentItems as PTS ON PTS.ItemID = IT.ID 
                             WHERE IT.ID = #tmpHierarchy.ItemID
                ) 
           IN
               (
               SELECT Item FROM #tmpHierarchy WHERE pLevel = 2
               )
           )
```

This would be about what I want to achive, but it returns

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

...for obvious reason, that I have more then one value in IN clause (?).

I would be pleased to get some suggestions to this problem.

Regards,

Oak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so modifing second condition to INNER JOIN seems to give correct results:

```
              AND EXISTS (
                         SELECT ParItem.ID
                         FROM Items as IT
                         LEFT JOIN ParentItems as PTS ON PTS.ItemID = IT.ID 
                         LEFT JOIN Items as ParItem on ParItem.ID = PTS.ParentItemID
                         INNER JOIN #tmpHierarchy as H ON H.ItemID = ParItem.ID 
                         WHERE IT.ItemID = HI.PartNo AND H.pLevel = 2
                         )
```

I hope it helps to future viewers.

Regards Oak

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is that part of the query:

```
SELECT Item FROM Items as IT LEFT JOIN ParentItems as PTS ON PTS.ItemID = IT.ID 
                         WHERE IT.ID = #tmpHierarchy.ItemID
```

It's return more than one row, and you get many to many comparison with is not allowed by IN clause.

You can chage query to something like this:

```
UPDATE  #tmpHierarchy
SET     pLevel = 3
WHERE   pLevel = 99
        AND EXISTS ( SELECT Item
                     FROM   Items AS IT
                            LEFT JOIN ParentItems AS PTS ON PTS.ItemID = IT.ID
                     WHERE  IT.ID = #tmpHierarchy.ItemID
                            AND Item IN ( SELECT    Item
                                          FROM      #tmpHierarchy
                                          WHERE     pLevel = 2 ) );
```

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in the question, I know this will not work... I would like to know how to resolve this. Obviously, the outcome of this particular select will return usually either NULL, or 1 item, but sometimes an item has more then one parents (few max). In no way it is a large set of items. But I need to handle this cross-comparison within the UPDATE.

Comment: I add corrected query that should meet your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

If you use IN, the left subquery must be a "one row" result, try this:

```
UPDATE #tmpHierarchy SET pLevel = 3 WHERE pLevel = 99 
      AND (
            SELECT Item 
            FROM ParentItems as PTS WHERE PTS.ItemID = #tmpHierarchy.ItemID AND
                   #tmpHierarchy.pLevel = 2
           ) IS NOT NULL
```

I assume that the item is of ParentItems.

This is my first comment on the site , any tips or complaints feel free to do.

edited:
Now i see, since SELECT ... pLevel = 99 ... (#tmpHierarchy.pLevel = 2 is impossible), solved by the owner with the right joins in the EXISTS.

Comment: I think you are missing a where clause in your inner query. You also have an extra ON that needs to be removed.

Comment: I think there's something missing too, but it would probably steer me in a correct direction. I managed to achieve that with INNER JOIN in the meanwhile...

Comment: I edited my comment, changing the ON by WHERE, tanks for the advise.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, as I said, I think it is a correct answer. It is also a bit simplier than the code I have now, so I will test it as soon as I overcome a pressure from the immediate need for a running code.